# How to add extra 24VAC wire (C wire)

Tags: heating, wire, cooling, heat

I  have recently bought a Honeywell rth9580 programmable WiFi thermostat. Unfortunately I have old electric heating/cooling system probably from 70's. The system is based on two relays (I guess heating and cooling).  Since transformer doesn't have 3rd wire (C?) by default I would like to make one by connecting extra wire to transformer chassis. Having terminal C I would like to connect wire G  to terminal C and jump terminal G with Y. I measured the voltage between transformer chassis and Rh wire: idle 34VAC,  calling for heating/cooling 24VAC. Here are my questions:
1) Is this setup will work? 
2) Is it safe to connect thermostat since voltage on idle is a bit higher than it supposed to? 
3) Am I right to assume that transformer won't overheat because thermostat will try to drain to many amps?